# "Managing" server side commandcolumn click

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

How can I "manage" server side event after a click on a command column?
Take look at my code:`

```
<ext:CommandColumn Width="60">
  <Commands>
    <ext:GridCommand Icon="ClockStart" CommandName="CloseTicket">
      <ToolTip Text="Chiudi Ticket" />
    </ext:GridCommand>
    <ext:GridCommand Icon="ArrowJoin" CommandName="Riassegna">
      <ToolTip Text="Assegna ad altro gruppo/utente" />
    </ext:GridCommand>
  </Commands>`
</ext:CommandColumn>
```

How can I "assign" server side events? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign a server side event, as in a method defined in your codebehind you need to setup a directevent on your grid panel for the 'Command' event as below:

```
<DirectEvents>
    <Command OnEvent="Command_Handler"></Command>
</DirectEvents>
```

Then your event handler for this command needs to determine which command was pressed, perhaps by using command name or the suchlike and performing the appropriate action.